# When using the hook useState, it will be executed again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have code for the validation form in the next js V1

```
setErrorF((errorF) => {
  if(
    errorF.FNameAndLName !== "" ||
    errorF.phoneNumber !== "" ||
    errorF.location1 !== "" ||
    errorF.gender !== "" ||
    errorF.methodeOfCourse !== ""
    ){
      handleAlertinfo("خطاها را بررسی کنید.");
      return errorF;
    }
    return errorF;
});
```

this code runs two times but I want to run for one time
I want to use update errorF in the useState but that runs two times how can solve that?

Comment: Where exactly is this code located, how and when is it called? Where is the `useState`, how is that initialised? What is `handleAlertinfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two times execution caused by **React Strict Mode**. Since Next.js 13.4, **Strict Mode** is enabled by default with app router. As documented [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect), *When Strict Mode is on, React will run one extra development-only setup+cleanup cycle before the first real setup. This is a stress-test that ensures that your cleanup logic “mirrors” your setup logic and that it stops or undoes whatever the setup is doing*. If You want your code to run once, you can implement the [cleanup function](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development).

Comment: /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;  work for me thanks